# How to send a task to Celery without waiting?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have the following code in my `tasks.py` file:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def create_car(self, car):
    if car is None:
        return False
    status = subprocess.run(["<some_command_to_run>"])
    return True
```

It should run the command `<some_command_to_run>` but for some reason the website waits it to finish. I thought the whole point of Celery that it will be run in the background and return status. How can I submit this task in asynchronous way? The wanted behaviour: user asked to create a new car instance, it will add a task to the queue and return true that indicating that the car was requested correctly. In the background it will run that command and return (somewhere - not sure yet where) that status. How to do it?

Comment: Could you share with us how you run this command ?

Comment: We need to know how your run the create_car task.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou Oh sure, I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to call `create_car.delay(instance.pk)`, `delay()` make it async.

it's JSON encoded so make sure to pass only primary key or json serializable data (model instance is not)

Be carefull because `post_save` is not async too :)

Comment: What is `instance.pk`?

Comment: `pk` is a shortcut for PrimaryKey, it can be `id` or whatever you defined, that will just replace the real query with the real primary key. Doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut

Comment: did you forget to launch celery server ?

Comment: Once I passed `instance.pk`, how do I get the actual `car` object?

Comment: `instance = Model.objects.get(pk=parameter_pk)`

Comment: Yeah but what should `Model` be? If in `cars/models.py` you import `from tasks import create_car` and in `tasks.py` you import `from cards.models import Car`, you'll get a circle.

Comment: just import it in your task function